# Dynamic variable re-evaluation in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am a newbie in Windows batch scripting and probably this is a common question, answered multiple times. The problem I have is with the following script:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set var1=1
echo var1 = %var1%
set var2=var1 init value : %var1%, var1 delayed value : !var1!

set var1=2
echo var1 = %var1%
echo var2 = !var2!

endlocal
```

The current output is:

```
var1 = 1
var1 = 2
var2 = var1 init value : 1, var1 delayed value : 1
```

, however the desired output should be:

```
var1 = 1
var1 = 2
var2 = var1 init value : 1, var1 delayed value : 2
```

How can this be achieved, any ideas? How can be the var2 variable somehow re-evaluated, after var1 changes its value? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean somehng like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set var1=1
echo var1 = %var1%
set var2=var1 init value : %var1%, var1 delayed value : %%var1%%

set var1=2
echo var1 = %var1%
call echo var2 = %var2%

endlocal
```

Sample output:

```
var1 = 1
var1 = 2
var2 = var1 init value : 1, var1 delayed value : 2
```

When var2 is set the double percent signs evaluate to single ones,
the call echo forces another evaluation, now expanding the actual value of var1

Comment: **Precisely** what I had. The point is that `delayedexpansion` is not required here since the `call echo` workaround is used for the runtime value of the variable. In OP's code, **both** are substituted because the `set` does not execute on a *varying* value - at that time, `%var%` and `!var!` are the same thing.

Comment: It worked like a charm, I was unaware of this trick with the "nested" expansion of the percent signs. Many thanks for the prompt answer, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In first place, this is *not* a "common newbie question"; what you want to do is somewhat unusual...

You need to do two small changes in your code:

- In this line: `set var2=var1 init value : %var1%, var1 delayed value : !var1!` the values of both normal `%var1%` and delayed `!var1!` expansions are *the same*. You want not store *the value* of `!var1!` in `var2`, but *the literal string* `!var1!`, so when you later expand `var2`, such a string be re-expanded. To do so you need to escape the exclamation marks; this is done with a caret this way: `"^!var1^!"` when the string is enclosed in quotes, or with a triple-caret this way: `^^^!var1^^^!` otherwise (an escaped-caret plus an escaped-exclamation mark).
- Obviously, if you want a *double-expansion* of the string in `var2`, then the first one must be a standard `%var2%` expansion, *not* a delayed `!var2!` one.

This is the final code with the two previous changes:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set var1=1
echo var1 = %var1%
set var2=var1 init value : %var1%, var1 delayed value : ^^^!var1^^^!

set var1=2
echo var1 = %var1%
echo var2 = %var2%
```